# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection Kotlin version

Tags: android, kotlin

I know the problem keeps coming up. I was looking for different solutions but in the end I still have the same error with annotated with @Entity.
Tests a simple Dao database. I know how to solve this problem using SQLiteDatabase. But I want to learn to use Dao.

```
    @Entity     //(tableName = "employee-table")
    data class EmplyeeEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int=0,
        var name: String="",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "email-id")
        var email: String="")

    @Database(entities=[EmplyeeEntity::class],version=2)
    abstract class EmployeeDataBase:RoomDatabase() {
        abstract fun employeeDao():EmployeeDao
        companion object{
            @Volatile
            private var INSTANCE:EmployeeDataBase?=null
            fun getInstance(context: Context):EmployeeDataBase{
                synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        EmployeeDataBase::class.java,
                        "employee_database"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }

        }
    }
}


    @Dao
    interface EmployeeDao {
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        suspend fun insert(entity:EmplyeeEntity)
        @Update
        suspend fun update(entity:EmplyeeEntity)
        @Delete
        suspend fun delete(entity:EmplyeeEntity)
        @Query("SELECT * FROM EmplyeeEntity")
        fun fetcheAllEmployees():Flow<List<EmplyeeEntity>>
        @Query("SELECT * FROM EmplyeeEntity where id=:id")
        @JvmSuppressWildcards
        fun fetcheAllEmployeesById(id:Int):Flow<List<EmplyeeEntity>>
    }

    class EmployeeApp:Application() {
        val db by lazy {
            EmployeeDataBase.getInstance(this)
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        def room_version = '2.3.0'
        def activityVersion = '1.3.1'
        def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-beta01"
        // Room and Lifecycle dependencies
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
        //kotlin extensions for coroutine support with room
        implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
        //kotlin extension for coroutine support with activities
        implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

I think the problem is mine dependencies...I've been blaming for a few days now: P

Comment: If you recently updated to Kotlin 1.6.0, updated your `room` to `2.4.0-rc01`

Comment: Works fine, thank you very much :)